# Combinatorics-how many paths

Tags: combinatorics, triangles

How many paths with length 9 (1 is a length of 1 edge) you have in order to get from point A to B (you are allowed to trace back the edge you just walked) in the picture

[image]

Comment: $2*4=8$? What do you mean by "backward"?

Comment: There may be simple ways of tallying those paths, but I might simply build a collection of generating functions enumerating paths of prescribed lengths starting from $A$ to any other vertex.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have the time for that project today. I'm sure others could assist you. But, please study [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) first.

Comment: @farruhota I'm fairly sure *you can go backward*  means that you are allowed to trace back the edge you just walked. Also, I cannot fathom how you got 8 as the answer. There are a lot more. Starting from B there are four obvious loops of length 2 and six of length 3. Implying that there are at least $4^3+6^2$ paths of length six from B to B. Preceding any of those by any of the four obvious paths of length three from A to B gives already $4(4^3+6^2)$ distinct paths of length nine. And I haven't counted all the paths, yet.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtohen, right, the path must have length $9$, I thought it was referring to the lengths of the figure and counted the number of paths. Agreed, it would be too simple.

Comment: If you can go backwards then there infinite paths. Just circle on one up to infinite times. Every path is unique. Did you mean you allowed once to walk on same path.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtohen, is starting from $B$ and looping to itself permitted? In other words, once $B$ is reached from $A$ in $3$ units, can it leave $B$ and loop to $B$ two times?

Answer (score 8):

Build the "adjacency matrix" of this graph. I'll call the middle two vertices $X$ and $Y$, and the bottom vertices (other than $B$) $Z$ and $W$. If we order the vertices: $\{A,B,X,Y,Z,W\}$, then the adjacency matrix is

$$ M = \left( \begin {array}{cccccc}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end {array} \right)
$$

This encodes which vertices are connected by an edge. For example, the first row means $A$ connects to $X$ and $Y$, but not to any other vertices. Taking powers of this matrix counts paths of certain lengths.

So in your case $M^9$ will be the matrix which counts the number of paths of length 9 between any two vertices. So you want the $(1,2)$ entry of $M^9$.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the statement that powers of the adjacency matrix count paths of certain lengths?  I don't doubt that it's true, but it's not immediately obvious to me.  Thanks.

Comment: By definition of matrix multiplication, the $(i,j)$ entry of $M^2$ is $\sum_k m_{ik} m_{kj}$. Since all entries are $0$ or $1$, each term in this sum will be $0$ or $1$. It will be one if both $m_{ik}$ and $m_{kj}$ are $1$, and $0$ if either is $0$. Both $m_{ik}$ and $m_{kj}$ being $1$ means that there is a path of length 2 from $i$ to $j$, going through $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach it is to make $10$ copies of the diagram.  The first counts the number of ways to get to each vertex in $0$ moves, so has $1$ at vertex $A$ and $0$ everywhere else.  The next has the number of ways to get to each vertex in $1$ move.  It will have $1$s at the two vertices in the second layer, the one between $A$ and $B$.  Each successive copy has the number of ways to get to each vertex in one move more than the one before.  Each vertex in $k$ moves gets the sum of the numbers at all the vertices it is connected to from the $k-1$ move drawing because you could have gotten to each of those vertices in $k-1$ moves in the number of ways shown, then moved to the vertex in question with the $k^{th}$ move.

The adjacency matrix approach really encodes this thinking.